# proper syntax after escape?

Tags: php, sql, syntax

what would be the proper syntax to write after the escape?

```
("SELECT torrent_download
FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "auctions WHERE
                auction_id='" . $item_details['auction_id'] . );
```

the error i am getting is unexpected ')'

I tried various " and ' but none seem to work

Comment: @j08691: Please post that as an answer instead of a comment so that I can downvote it. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you are missing a closing `'` for `$item_details['auction_id']`, before the final `)`, which would get enclosed in double quotes as `"'");`

```
("SELECT torrent_download
  FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "auctions WHERE
            auction_id='" . $item_details['auction_id'] . "'");
```

To save a little bit of trouble in the double-quoted string, I recommend using the `{}` enclosure instead of concatenating all the quotes.  You cannot enclose the constant `DB_PREFIX`, however.

```
("SELECT torrent_download
  FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "auctions WHERE
        auction_id='{$item_details['auction_id']}'");
```

Comment: If he used prepared statements that wouldn't have happened :p

Answer (score 1):

```
("SELECT torrent_download
 FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "auctions WHERE
            auction_id='" . $item_details['auction_id'] . "'");
```

Did you try that? It's " followed by ' followed by " again.

Answer (score 0):

```
("SELECT torrent_download
FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "auctions WHERE
            auction_id='" . $item_details['auction_id'] ."'" );
```